# Sending and performing commands from node.js to bash

Tags: node.js, socket.io, asterisk

I'm developing a sort of [Flash Operator Pannel](http://www.fop2.com/) for Asterisk but, with Node.js and Socket.io instead of depending of Flash.

I've polished the node server and the front end **BUT** I don't know how could I send events from Asterisk to node server and do things that will be sended over the socket.

Given the fact that we have a heavily tuned Asterisk to suit our company needs, connecting to the AMI nor the Asterisk socket will solve my problem because we aren't working with real extensions.

So, despite the Asterisk part, I want to know how could I send info to node through bash or curls or whatever

I thought about using curls to the server but this could cause that someone who knows the commands (pretty unlikely) could alter the application flow with unreal data.

EDIT: Rethinking about it, I would just want to be able to receive requests through the socket/server ??? and then be able to perform actions that will be emited through socket.io.

Is that even possible?

Comment: I would be interested to know if you complete this project. Search my nick on google for how to contact me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really depends upon what specific data you are trying to get from Asterisk to Node. You're trying to replace the Flash Operator Panel, yet you don't have real extensions. I'm guessing that you are using Asterisk as an SBC/proxy of sorts.

If you truly want an event-driven approach, I suggest modifying your dialplan to reach out to Node whenever needed, with whatever data you want. This would most easily be achieved by calling an AGI script with some number of arguments (written in whatever language) that then connects to Node via an HTTP POST, socket, or other.

If you want a more passive approach, you could have Node stream-read the asterisk log files for data, or, as already suggested, connect to the Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI) and stream from there. Contrary to what has been stated previously, I don't consider this to be a very daunting task.

Answer (score 0):

You want to open a socket from Node to Asterisk's AMI (asterisk manager interface). I never used Node, but I would imagine the code would look roughly like this:

```
var astman = new net.socket().connect(5038);//connect to port 5039 on localhost
astman.on('data', function(data) {
    //do something with received data
});
```

One of the most well maintained ami libraries are FreePBX's [php-astmanager](http://www.freepbx.org/trac/browser/freepbx/branches/2.10/amp_conf/htdocs/admin/libraries/php-asmanager.php). While it's written in php, it should give you a pretty good idea of what your need to do.

Comment: Hi there @Mbrevda the problem comes when you customize Asterisk to the limit and performs actions on Dialplan to retrieve needed info in order to re-route the call. So, if I connect to the Socket I would receive a lot of info that isn't needed nor it's usable. So, basically I would be doing the same I do in Asterisk but in node.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna - unfortunately, that is how Asterisk works. 
The beauty of Asterisk though is how it works with outside services. Instead of burning cycles developing, implementing, and then running items to help the user get exactly what they want, asterisk gives you  diret access to the "firehose". You get EVERYTHING*. Now, feel free to filter just those ones you want. Did you see the lib I linked to? If you port that to js, you will have most of your work cut out for you

*with some exception: the asterisk manager can apply some COARSE filters - see manager permissions/manager.conf for more

Comment: The main issue is that we are not using real extensions and we use dinamic queues got from MySQL. Both agents and queues are got from database. That flexibility doesn't exists in Asterisk AS IS that's why we managed this in that way.

Comment: Thats the way most do it - again, see FreePBX. How do you feel your agent types affects the way you receive commands from Asterisk?

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly set up your node.js program to listen on a socket for messages from Asterisk. But you'd have to roll your own connection management scheme, authentication scheme, message durability (possibly), etc.

Alternatively -- and especially if there is the node server and asterisk server are not on the same machine -- you could use a message queue program like RabbitMQ. That takes care of a lot of the important details involved in interprocess communications. It's pretty easy, too. On the node side, check out https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp

Answer (score -1):

I've never used Asterisk but running command line programs can be done with the child_process module.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html